# wxPython: Get old value and insertion point in a wx.TextCtrl

Tags: wxpython

When the value of a `wx.TextCtrl` is changed, the event `wx.EVT_TEXT` is emitted. Calling `GetValue()` in the event handler returns the new value. Calling `GetInsertionPoint()` in the event handler returns the new insertion point. Is it possible to get the old value and the old insertion point (before the text change is made)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. However you could just save off the value and insertion point when the text control is created. These will be an empty string and zero (respectively), I believe.

Then in the `EVT_TEXT` event handler, you would just update the saved values whenever something changes.

Comment: I thought of this when only text value was concerned. But then I found changing the insertion point alone doesn't emit a `wx.EVT_TEXT` event. So once the text is changed you lose the old insertion point. This makes implementing an Undo feature much more difficult since every time you restore the old text the cursor is in the end but not where it used to be.

Comment: This bit of documentation has some insight into the problem: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.TextCtrl.html#phoenix-title-textctrl-text-format

Comment: If you want to implement an undo/redo function, you should just use `StyledTextCtrl` as it has this functionality built-in: http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/undo-mechanism-td2311430.html

Comment: `StyledTextCtrl` might be a choice for undo/redo, but at this stage I'm not really sure whether we need to keep historical insertion points for other use (for example log analysis). And yeah I looked into the official doc of `TextCtrl` but it doesn't tell how to get the *old* insertion point...